# Spring Batch Admin Home Page

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Is there a way to change what should be home page for spring batch admin webapp?

I tried various solutions and nothing helps. What bothers me is that `RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" })` is bidden to `HomeController` inside `spring-batch-resources` project, and I can't override that mapping.

I didn't know what would be necessary, I first tried redefining `index.jsp` page to farward to `"/myHomePage"` instead of `"/home"` that is by default. No result.

I tried defining my own controller to have same `RequestMapping(value = "/")`. No result. Ambiguous mappings exception.

I tried extending and overriding method from `HomeController` in my own controller, also without result, also ambiguous mappings exception.

I even added

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

NO RESULT!
I don't care much about `"/home"` mapping I just want to override `"/"` mapping, or to forward it to my page, or something like that. Is there a way?

P.S. I can't change `HomeController` implementation, since it is `spring-batch-resources` dependency for `spring-batch-admin-sample`...

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation for the answer I've given in comments, requested by @kap**

It's been a long time since I worked on this, and I don't have the code available now, but as I can remember:

In one of the definitions for the application-context in XML files in resources (sorry I forgot which one) you need to add something like

```
<mvc:interceptor>
   <mvc:mapping path="/"/>
   <bean class="blabla.MyInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```

and then create class **MyInterceptor** that implements **HandlerInterceptor**  which will redirect the request. There are 3 methods you can use to override the behavior

- **preHandle**
- **postHandle**
- **afterCompletion**

and I think that I used **postHandle** to implement code for redirect to my custom homepage. You can google for tutorials on redirection of requests using Spring interceptors to see how to implement that.

Comment: Great, works like a charm, thanks. I used the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` which has already preHandle and afterCompletion pre-implemented.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:
adding this to web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Batch Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/batch/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and adding this part on my own index page

```
<body>
<div class="pageHeader" id="pageHeader" style="height: 100px;"></div>
<p><a href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/batch/">Batch job admin</a></p>
</body>
```

Comment: I guess you have `batch-admin` as part of some other webapp of yours. And then you can add another servlet mapping just for it... But I just use `spring-batch-admin-sample`, and override it's settings.

I managed to override it by, implementing Interceptor for handling mapping `<mvc:mapping path="/"/>`

Thanks anyway... I see very few SO users doing something with spring batch :(
Thank you, for suggestion!

Comment: not really, it is not part of some other web-app, we just separated the spring-batch module from spring-batch-admin. anyway, your way seems to be cleaner. Yes unfortunately, not many developers use spring batch, let alone with spring batch admin :-\

Comment: @tibortru can you please elaborate on your Interceptor aproach?

Comment: @kap I added the answer above,I hope it helps ;)